# Table Schema Not Working After Upgrade to .Net 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am in the process of upgrading an application from .net core 3.1 to .net 5.  Everything works except the EF database calls are not using the defined schema that is set in the object model.

The object currently had then data annotations.

```
[Table("Report", Schema = "rpt")]
public class Report
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
}
```

When the query is created the table schema is not included. The result is that the query fails because the table object is not found.

```
SELECT [r].[ReportId]
FROM [Report] AS [r]
ORDER BY [r].[ReportName]
```

You can see that the table schema is not included. The query should be:

```
SELECT [r].[ReportId]
FROM [rpt].[Report] AS [r]
ORDER BY [r].[ReportName]
```

Thank you for your help.

---

Last migration script before the upgrade to .net 5

```
public partial class UpdateSchema : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "GenesisTokenAccess",
            newName: "GenesisTokenAccess",
            newSchema: "rpt");
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.RenameTable(
            name: "GenesisTokenAccess",
            schema: "rpt",
            newName: "GenesisTokenAccess");
    }
}
```

Comment: can u share the migration scripts that creates the schema on the table?

Comment: Yes but the migration has not been run since the upgrade to .net 5. But I can share the latest.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - it works as expected which you can easily see if try the posted model in a new clean project. There must be something else in your real code not shown here which is causing it.

Comment: I have confirmed that if I create a new project and add these models and create a migration that the proper schema is created. When I run a Add-Migration on the current DbContext a migration is created but the table is in the dbo schema instead of the rpt schema. Also If I change the table name with the TableAttridute it is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code that was legacy. It was causing the schema issues after upgrading to 5.0.11 from 3.X in the OnModelCreating method

```
foreach (var entityType in builder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    // Use the entity name instead of the Context.DbSet<T> name
    // refs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables#conventions
    builder.Entity(entityType.ClrType).ToTable(entityType.ClrType.Name);
 }
```